Why does the CPU time increase significantly even though I use the noEvent operator in OpenModelica?
When I simulate the following model, the CPU time increases unexpectedly:
model WithoutChatter
  Real x;
initial equation
  x = 2;
equation
  der(x) = if noEvent(x>=1) then -1 else 1;
end WithoutChatter;

With the noEvent operator, the CPU time should not go up noticeably, like it is explained here, from where I copied the example code:
Modelica by Example
I am new to OpenModelica and just did a Windows installation. For the simulation I used default settings. The result is this.
CPU time increases

Using noEvent to reduce chattering is not a good idea. Depending on the solver it can slow down the simulation even more (or have no impact).
The reason is that the solvers assume that the model is sufficiently continuous. Breaking that once in a while as for if x>=0 then sqrt(x) else 0 is sort of ok - but breaking it every nano-second (or even more often) with x>=0 then -1 else 1 is not.
The only good solution is to rewrite the model - that's why friction models have three states: forward sliding, backward sliding, and stuck.
The exact impact on performance will depend on the solver (including its error estimator).

If I understood this correctly, no events are responsible for the high CPU time in this case. The noEvent operator is working correctly. This point is important to me,

To be clear: the high CPU time is caused by the lack of continuity due to adding noEvent.

In some cases where generating a state event could cause the model to become extremely slow would smoothing the output using a function like Modelica.Fluid.Utilities.regStep() be something to consider? Obviously the user will need to consider what this smoothing will mean for the characteristics/accuracy of the model.

Yes, smoothing the function using something like regStep can avoid both overhead of the event and solver slowdown due to the discontinuity - provided that the regularization part is "wide enough".
